# How to continue with the click event after deleting it with preventDefault method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, preventdefault

I have a link and I cancel the "click" event with .preventDefault method to check if a user is logged in. If the user is logged in with the correct role I want to continue with the click effect following the link, home?

```
jQuery('.btn-read-more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    var data = {
        action: 'is_user_logged_in'
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response === 'no') {
            jQuery('#modal_login_form_div').modal('show');
        } else if (response === 'ccwdpo_user' || response === 'ccwdpo_customer') {
            //e.currentTarget.click();
            //console.log(e.currentTarget);
            window.location = jQuery(this).attr("href");    
        }
    });
});
```

For now, I solved with:

```
jQuery('.permalink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        action: 'is_user_logged_in'
    };

    var permalink = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    //console.log(permalink);
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response === 'no') {
            jQuery('#modal_login_form_div').modal('show');
        } else if (response === 'ccwdpo_user' || response === 'ccwdpo_customer') {
            window.location = permalink;
        } else {
            jQuery('#modal_error_div').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is inside the post callback. Store a reference to `this` or the `href` outside the post

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. Get the `href` value from the event and set `window.location`:

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = ev => {
  // Prevent default
  ev.preventDefault();
  // Continue with action (note this does not handle if other attributes, such as `target="_blank"` is set)
  window.location = ev.target.getAttribute('href');
};
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Go to google</a>
```

Comment: I don't understand why I get an infinite loop... :(

Comment: Where are you getting an infinite loop?